# JavaScript not working on one site but fine on the other

Tags: javascript

This is why I have always hated Javascript since it always does weird things like this... I added this EXACT code in a script without a single problem, then I paste the EXACT code in another and it doesnt work at all.  So frustrating.  Here is the code what is the problem please?  Also if you could make it work by elementID instead of form name that would be great thanks

```
<script language="javascript" type="javascript">
<!-- 
function randomPassword(length)
{
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-+<>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890";
    pass = "";
for(x=0;x<length;x++)
{
     i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 67);
     pass += chars.charAt(i);
}
return pass;
}

function formSubmit()
{
    myform.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
    return false;
}
// -->
</script>


<form name="myform" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="120">Username:</td>
      <td><input name="update_username" type="text" value="" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input name="row_password" type="text" size="40"> &nbsp; <input type="button"         class="button" value="Generate" onClick="javascript:formSubmit();" tabindex="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: have you checked console log? you may got syntex error.

Comment: The name of the form it is shown above.

Comment: remove <!-- from script code... or comment it

Comment: still doesnt work if you copy and paste this on a site and view it you will see it work wont.  Yet it works on another script I use just fine.

Comment: Could you please offer a running version of your code at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @MrJ did you see my answer??

Answer (score 1):

removed `javascript:` added `document.myform` and  changed... `randomPassword(myform.update_username.value.length);` now seems to work.. .  [JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/EdINuYI/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
function randomPassword(length)
{
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-+<>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234567890";
    pass = "";

for(x=0;x<length;x++)
{
     i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 67);
     pass += chars.charAt(i);
}
return pass;
}

function formSubmit()
{
document.myform.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.update_username.value.length);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `formSubmit` is expecting the form to have the name `passform`. Change the form accordingly, or change the code to use `myform` instead of `passform`.

Alternatively, you can change the code to take the form as a parameter:

```
function formSubmit(frm) {
  frm.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
  return false;
}
```

Then call it using:

```
onclick="formSubmit(this.form);"
```

You are missing a field called `length` in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="length" value="10">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/DDn6W/

Side notes: Don't use `javascript:` when you are putting code in an event attribute. That's only used when you put code in an `href` attribute. Don't use `<!--` and `-->` inside the `script` tag. That is an ancient construct to keep code from showing up in the page in browsers that doesn't know what the `script` tag is for. Those doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Oops sorry ignore that, I just edited for this question the passform is myform it still doesnt work

Comment: OK I tried that new code and it doesnt work.  Does it work on your end?  I used Firefox and Chrome and nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: @MrJ: There was a `length` field missing also, see my edit above. I added a link to a working example.

Answer (score 0):

`passform.row_password.value` is looking for a form named "passform", but in this code you have `<form name="myform">`.

In any case, that is an outdated and potentially harmful way to access elements - though, judging by the fact that you are still using HTML comments to hide your code from "older" browsers, I doubt you've picked up a JavaScript book from this milennium :p

Your `randomPassword` function is fine, but change your `formSubmit` is wrong in a couple ways.

- Aside from the accessing of the wrong form, it is also trying to access a field called "length", which is absent from this form.
- You should assign IDs to the elements you want to access in JavaScript, and use `document.getElementById('someID')` to get them.
- You aren't actually calling `formSubmit` anywhere. Did you maybe have an `onClick` or `onSubmit` event handler?

Comment: Yes please ignore the passform I already edited my post the code doesnt have passform in it only myform and it still doesnt work